# TSQL - Convert Rows per record to Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Consider the following table:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GUID   | DeviceGUID | DetailGUID | sValue  | iValue  | gValue  | DateStored  |
| ENTRY1 | DEVICE1    | Detail1    | SN112   |         |         | 01/01/2020  |
| ENTRY2 | DEVICE1    | Detail4    |         | 1241    |         | 01/01/2020  |
| ENTRY3 | DEVICE1    | Detail7    |         |         | GUID12  | 01/01/2020  |
| ENTRY4 | DEVICE2    | Detail1    | SN111   |         |         | 01/01/2020  |
| ENTRY5 | DEVICE2    | Detail2    | RND123  |         |         | 01/01/2020  |
| ENRTY6 | DEVICE2    | Detail4    |         | 2351    |         | 03/01/2020  |
| ENTRY7 | DEVICE3    | Detail1    | SN100   |         |         | 02/01/2020  |
| [...]  | [...]      | [...]      |         |         |         |             |
|        |            |            |         |         |         |             |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have a table which links a DeviceGUID with a DetailsGUID, with the idea of having unlimited options for Details (just create a new detail and it will be fetchable). however, this means I have a finite and unknown amount of records per deviceGUID.

What I want to show to my users is a table like this:

```
+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GUID   | DeviceGUID |Detail1 |Detail2 |Detail4 |Detail7 |DateStored          |
| ENTRY1 | DEVICE1    |SN112   | [NULL] |1241    |GUID12  | [MAX DateStored]   |
| ENTRY2 | DEVICE2    |SN111   | RND123 |2351    | [NULL] | [MAX DateStored]   |
| ENTRY3 | DEVICE3    |SN100   |        |        |        |                    |
| [...]  | [...]      |        |        |        |        |                    |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have been searching a bit and found the `PIVOT` option but that only seems to function for one field,
another option was `CROSS APPLY`, but that (seems to) need to convert everything to the same datatype; as I hope is visible n the ColumnNames, I will have 3 types of data: String (`VARCHAR`) value, `Integer`  value, GUID (`uniqueidentifier`) value, and they will not be interchangeable (meaning Detail with GUID Detail1 will always have a `VARCHAR`, Detail with DetailGUID Detail4 will always be an `Integer`

what I was able to find out until now:

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @columns = N'';
SELECT @columns+=N', p.'+QUOTENAME([Name])
FROM
(
    SELECT GUID AS [Name]
    FROM [dbo].Details AS p
) AS x;

SET @sql = N'
SELECT [DeviceObjectGUID], '+STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '')+' FROM (
SELECT [DeviceObjectGUID], [DateStored], [DetailGUID] as [Name] 
    FROM [dbo].[DeviceDetails]) AS j PIVOT (MAX(DateStored) FOR [Name] in 
       ('+STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p.[', ',['), 1, 1, '')+')) AS p;';
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

to make a dynamic PIVOT for transposing the data.. but as mentioned this is limited to one column

and

```
select DeviceObjectGUID, value
from DeviceDetails
cross apply
(
  select 'sValue', cast(sValue as varchar(MAX)) union all
  select 'gValue', cast(gValue as varchar(MAX))union all
  select 'iValue', cast(iValue as varchar(MAX))
) c(col, value)
```

This will have me converting all fields to VARCHAR..

One other option I tried (to understand PIVOT) was this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT *
    FROM [dbo].[DeviceDetails]
) AS SourceTable 
    PIVOT(
    max(sValue)FOR [DetailGUID] IN(
        [450533BB-43B2-499B-B2F7-094BFAE949B0],
        [7483E518-EB61-4B72-93F7-0F97BBFAFA01],
        [29B1BDE8-3AD4-4576-8B76-3CAE83E10B11],
        [5FC8CC76-12EB-4924-9320-5D09BBE97C10],
        [789AA79B-B1DF-4BA2-860A-7129B39D341F],
        [C90F4EFE-D848-4BAB-96BF-8DC6BF4F6E62],
        [EC6A4ED3-1475-4B0A-8E08-B2F4E095622F],
        [D442B7CA-5825-49D9-9977-D88770304B57],
        [99B70FEE-999B-4D44-83E9-EB8119B15930],
        [3F83ED76-8CC3-4B3D-936A-F528DEB6C045]
        )
    ) AS PivotTable;
```

(The GUIDS in the '`IN` clause are the DetailGUIDs)
this almost gets me what I want, except that it is not dynamic and the fact that it is still limited to one data column. (`max(sValue)`) in this case.

===================

in response to

[image: PIVOTissue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as simple as that:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT DeviceGUID
          ,DetailGUID 
          ,CONCAT(sValue, iValue, gValue) as [value]
          ,DateStored 
    FROM my_table
) DS
PIVOT
(
    MAX([value]) FOR DetailGUID IN (......)
) PVT
```

Comment: CONCAT gets rid f the Type issue; however; this results in a table with one entry per deviceGUID, what it should give me is per available DetailGUID, fill the gValue,iValue or sValue -- added a screenshot with the output

Comment: Remove the `GUID` column.

Comment: That seems to do it.. let me verify

Comment: The issue is the `GUID` makes the rows unique and because of this cannot be grouped together.

Comment: Yes, same happens with the DateStored; thats why I still seem to get multiple rows in some occasions, but thats seems to be an issue in my data import...