# TSQL - PIVOT but CONCATENATE Fields

Tags: t-sql

in  [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63990368/tsql-convert-rows-per-record-to-columns/63991286?noredirect=1#comment113156426_63991286) I was assisted with my initial question. The answer supplied has been accepted because it was the actual answer to that question.

As an extention to that answer, please consider the same table:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GUID   | DeviceGUID | DetailGUID | sValue  | iValue  | gValue  | DateStored  |
| ENTRY1 | DEVICE1    | Detail1    | SN112   |         |         | 01/01/2020  |
| ENTRY2 | DEVICE1    | Detail4    |         | 1241    |         | 01/01/2020  |
| ENTRY3 | DEVICE1    | Detail7    |         |         | GUID12  | 01/01/2020  |
| ENTRY8 | DEVICE1    | Detail7    |         |         | GUID13  | 01/01/2020  |
| ENTRY9 | DEVICE1    | Detail7    |         |         | GUID14  | 01/01/2020  |
| ENTRY4 | DEVICE2    | Detail1    | SN111   |         |         | 01/01/2020  |
| ENTRY5 | DEVICE2    | Detail2    | RND123  |         |         | 01/01/2020  |
| ENRTY6 | DEVICE2    | Detail4    |         | 2351    |         | 03/01/2020  |
| ENTRY7 | DEVICE3    | Detail1    | SN100   |         |         | 02/01/2020  |
| [...]  | [...]      | [...]      |         |         |         |             |
|        |            |            |         |         |         |             |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The issue arises when there are multiple records with the same DetailGUID; PIVOT has been set to select 'MAX', I would not know exactly how that selects the actual record in this case, but that is not important.
Insteas of selecting one record and having it displayed, I need the records to be concatenated in a Comma Separated List, in the Pivot.

the current SQL query is as follows:

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX), @OrderGUID uniqueidentifier;
SET @OrderGUID = '1B470FFB-7410-4950-A3BC-B9D778C459D3';
SET @columns = N'';
SELECT @columns+=N', p.'+QUOTENAME([Name])
FROM
(
    SELECT GUID AS [Name]
    FROM [dbo].Details AS p
) AS x;

SET @sql = 
N'
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT DeviceObjectGUID
          ,DetailGUID 
          ,CONCAT(sValue, iValue, gValue) as [value]
          ,DateStored
    FROM DeviceDetails
    WHERE (DeviceObjectGUID IN (SELECT DeviceObjectGUID FROM DevicesPerOrder WHERE OrderGUID = ''' + CAST(@OrderGUID  as nVarchar(MAX) )+ '''))
) DS
PIVOT
(MAX([value]) FOR DetailGUID IN ('+STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p.[', ',['), 1, 1, '')+')) PVT';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

this will dynamically select all the detailGUIDS and transform them to headers; but I am unsure where I would start to input the CONCAT or TO XML statements